# How to Reference Enum in another project WPF

Tags: wpf, enums, binding

I'm trying to bind a combobox to a enum in different project but I have a problem;

Enum is defined in BTModels namespace as

```
namespace BTModels  
{  
  public   Enum FrequencyUnit  
  {  
     GHz,  
     MHz,   
     Khz,  
     Hz  
  }  
}
```

When I want to create ObjectDataProvider an error occurs "The name 'FrequencyUnit' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:BTModels'"

I have added xmlns:models="clr-namespace:BTModels" and code as:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" 
     x:Key="dataFromEnum">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="models:FrequencyUnit" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

My project look like this

[image: Mysolution]

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. When add another project xml definition must contain assembly info as follows:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:BTModels;assembly=BTModels"
```